# Need a valid file name! : Django -xhtml2pdf

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, xhtml2pdf

I need to get an image from database (entered by me on Django-admin interface),  and i need to display it in my pdf generated.

I have first get the image for each specifc user logged in like that in the **views.py**:

```
image1_full = CustomerPersonalData.objects.get(user_related=request.user)
obj_image1 = CustomerPersonalData._meta.get_field('image1')
value_image1 = str(obj_image1.value_from_object(image1_full))
```

in the **pdf_generated.html**, I have define it like that:

```
<img src="{{value_image1.url}}" />
```

----> but like that there is no image displayed.

PS: am using xhtml2pdf

the error displayed: Need a valid file name!

Comment: Hi  @K J , i have replaced in template from {{ value_image1.url }} to ---> {{ value_image1 }} but now it tell me also Need a valid file name!
'<img src="W_image.png"/>' , and there is no image displayed on the pdf generated , so  as you see in the terminal, it shows me just the right name without the path and it keeps tell me "Need a valid file name!"

Comment: no you did'nt get me i guess,  the image that i will got  that will be fetched is from the interface django-admin, even if i have choosed other images in the django admin it's doesn't give me any result...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Here is how I was able to implement it successfully. Hope it helps

url.py

```
path('foo/bar/<str:bar_id>/report/pdf/', getPdf,name="bar-report-pdf"),
```

process.py

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def html_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)

    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), 
                            result,
                            )
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

do not use the `link_callback` attribute of the pisaDocument when using external url

view.py

```
from foo.process import html_to_pdf 

def getPdf(request,bar_id):

    image_set = Bar.objects.filter(id=bar_id).all()
    
    context = {
        'title':"Inspection Report",
        "images": image_set,
        }

    open('templates/temp.html', "w").write(render_to_string('app/bar-report-pdf.html',context ))

    pdf = html_to_pdf('temp.html')
         
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

bar-report-pdf.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for image in images %}
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{{image.thumbnail_url_public}}" alt="{{forloop.counter}}">
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

here `image.thumbnail_url_public` is a text field containing public s3 image url. you can also use the presigned url if its a private s3 bucket.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after trying multiple solutions with base64 encoding the simplest solution was to replace `.url` with `.path` which worked on my windows dev server and my linux production server

```
<img src="{{value_image1.path}}" />
```